# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a contact form with php. When i fill up everything and press submit it's don't send any message to specific email address. it's show several error message.

**Error message:**

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect 
to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /homez.91
/maaks/www/hotel/eng/resellers.php on line 93

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the 
server could not be established in /homez.91/maaks/www/hotel/eng/resellers.php on line 
93

etc.....
```

**PHp Code:**

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['Send']) && $_POST['Send'] == "Submit")
        {
            $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $conum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['conum']);
            $country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
            $find = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['find']);
            $msg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);

            $err = array();


if(isset($fname) & isset($email) & isset($conum) & isset($country) & isset($find) & 
isset($msg))
            {

if(empty($fname) & empty($email) & empty($conum) & empty($country) & empty($find) & 
empty($msg))
                {
                    $err[] = "All field require";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(empty($fname))
                    $err[] = "Your first name require";
                }

            }
            else
            {
            if(!empty($err))
              {
                  foreach($err as $er)
                    {
                               echo "<font color=red>$er</font><br/>";
                    }
              }
            else
            {
                $to = "creativeart09@yahoo.com";
                $subject = "Message from Customer";
                        $message = "$msg";                                              
                        $from = "$email";
                        $headers = "From:" . $from;
                        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

                if(mail())
                    {

                    echo "<script>";
                            header("Refresh: 0; url=Thankyou.html");
                    echo "</script>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Something is wrong" . mysql_error();
                    }
                }
            }

        }           

 ?>
```

What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: yes, and i've Phpmyadmin in my server

Comment: have you tried mysql_connect() ?

Comment: But Why i use mysql_connect function? I just send email.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string() uses the mysql server to sanitize the string.

Comment: why do you need mysql_real_escape_string() if you're not storing the data in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to your mysql database before you can use the `mysql_real_escape_string` function. Also, mysql_* is deprecated in php and you should be using mysqli or pdo for your database work.

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string` is meant to protect a mysql database from injection attempts but you're just sending email.

Comment: Can i use mysqli without connect to database?

Comment: @Babu - I don't understand your problem. mysql and mysqli is for database stuff. It doesn't do anything but database stuff which needs a connection. I don't understand why you're even using the mysql function if all you're doing is sending email.